# custom button MouseLeave event

Tags: c#, .net, custom-controls, mouseevent

I made a custom button with some panels and pictureboxes. With the MouseEnter and MouseLeave I set the appropriate hover images like normal buttons.

The problem is that if I move the mouse too fast over the control it sometimes doesn't trigger the MouseLeave event. This way the button is "locked" in hover state.

screenshot problem:
http://www.jesconsultancy.nl/images/screens/screen_prblm.png

the button at the right is locked in "hover" state.

How can i solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: I kept trying this glitch for some time and I just can't get it to jam in the hovered state. Maybe you should post some code?

Comment: sure, Here it is: http://pastebin.com/Hh1d2pnc I had to give every panel and picturebox the click event and mouseleave because if I add the events to the user-control beneath it it wouldn't fire the events at all. With line 69 I check if the mouse had really left the control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Holy... That's a mess!
Firstly, `UserControl`s are very buggy. I suggest you make your control inherit from `Control` instead and draw the image and text yourself.
Secondly, why are you using reflection?
Thirdly, why are there so many controls?

This misses the event because it takes too much to update!

Here is some code for the simples control possible, that will NEVER miss an event:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace lol
{
    public class BlackWhiteControl : Control
    {
        protected override void OnMouseEnter(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnMouseEnter(e);

            this.BackColor = Color.Black;
        }

        protected override void OnMouseLeave(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnMouseLeave(e);

            this.BackColor = Color.White;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: lol, you're right, but I don't have a clue how I could draw the image and text myself. I have so many controls because every corner and sides needs a different picturebox. If I would use only 1 image for the button I couldn't resize it without stretching the image.

Comment: You don't have to. Send me the images and your current code file(s) (including designers) and I will send you a fully working control!

Comment: http://www.jesconsultancy.nl/JeS/cutom_btn.zip I could't find an email or PM system so here it is. 
Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Ok. I've saved it and I will make it it tomorrow morning. My mom threatened me to cut my throat if I don't go to sleep. (1:57 AM)

Comment: I've been woken up at 11 AM for f***'s sake, 3 hours earlier than usual, to go caroling... Anyway, I have a few minutes off now so I can make the control. :)

Comment: @Jelle I am done! It requires no images, updates lightning-fast and looks very smooth! I am counting on you to understand what I have done and modify everything by your own needs!  http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Eszg4Quh Edit: OOPS WRONG EVENTS! But I trust you will place the right events, right?

Comment: Thank you very much! I will look into it tomorrow because yesterday was a litle bit too late:P have to catch some sleep now.. If I can't figure it out I will email you, found your email on your website.

Comment: Cool! Wait, what? Did I put my e-mail in my website? O________O I need to see that! Edit: Where the hell did you get it from?

Comment: it is under Programs ->colorer ->visit colorer online help -> contact on http://vercas.webuda.com/ . Or isn't that your's ? 
Anyway, happy holidays!

Comment: Yes, it is mine. Send me an e-mail as fast as you can. Happy holidays!

Answer (score 0):

You should receive the WM_MOUSELEAVE windows message automatically when the mouse leaves the client area and the base class processing of this message will then call the OnMouseLeave method. If this is really not happening you can certainly get around it. Just intercept the WM_MOUSEMOVE directly and then make a Win32 API call that requests you be notified when the mouse leaves your control.

Use the following simple WndProc override...

```
        private bool _mouseOver = false;
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            switch (m.Msg)
            {
                case PI.WM_MOUSEMOVE:
                    if (!_mouseOver)
                    {
                        PI.TRACKMOUSEEVENTS tme = new PI.TRACKMOUSEEVENTS();
                        tme.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(PI.TRACKMOUSEEVENTS));
                        tme.dwHoverTime = 100;
                        tme.dwFlags = (int)(PI.TME_LEAVE);
                        tme.hWnd = Handle;
                        PI.TrackMouseEvent(ref tme);
                        _mouseOver = true;
                    }
                    base.WndProc(ref m);
                    break;
                case PI.WM_MOUSELEAVE:
                    _mouseOver = false;
                    base.WndProc(ref m);
                    break;
            }
        }
```

And the platform invoke information you need is...

```
    internal const int WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x0200;
    internal const int WM_MOUSELEAVE = 0x02A3;
    internal const int TME_LEAVE = 0x0002;

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct TRACKMOUSEEVENTS
    {
        public uint cbSize;
        public uint dwFlags;
        public IntPtr hWnd;
        public uint dwHoverTime;
    }
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: The problem isn't the event itself. The problem(s) is(are) the 7 picture boxes that require updating when that occurs.